# QObjectPicker slows down application

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt3d, pyside2

`QObjectPicker` which is set to *point picking* slows down my application due to the fact that I use entities with many many points, triangles, and meshes.

Is there a way to make my application faster. I assume it is possible to turn off picker and turn it on only when a user clicks a mouse (or triggers it in some other way).

My code is below.

I set picking settings in `Qt3DExtras.Qt3DWindow`:

```py
render_settings = self.renderSettings()
picking_settings = render_settings.pickingSettings()
picking_settings.setFaceOrientationPickingMode(Qt3DRender.QPickingSettings.FrontAndBackFace)
picking_settings.setPickMethod(Qt3DRender.QPickingSettings.PointPicking)            
picking_settings.setPickResultMode(Qt3DRender.QPickingSettings.NearestPick)
```

In my entities (`Qt3DCore.QEntity`) I implemented picker:

```py
self.picker = Qt3DRender.QObjectPicker(self)

self.picker.setHoverEnabled(True)
self.picker.setDragEnabled(True)
```

Comment: "Is there a way to make my application faster." Please, consider asking the question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com, where the optimization of a working code is in the focus.

Comment: There is an implicit question here that is clearly SO realm: "How can turn off point picking globally and turn it on only on mouse clicks?". If it were a [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/performance/info) question on CR, it would need much more context.

Comment: A suggestion I can make is to render a segmentation mask offscreen everytime the scene changes and use that to check which object the user is hovering or picking. For this you have to render each object with a unique color. You could do this using my offscreen renderer at https://github.com/Sonnentierchen/Qt3D-OffscreenRenderer and a custom material. If you need the precise 3D point as well. you could render another image that simply writes the XYZ coordinates as the fragment color and read it when the user clicks somewhere after determining the object using the segmentation image.